# ICMPv6 Protocol Unreachable (Protocol Not Supported)

Tags: sip, ipv6, icmp

SIP RFC 3261 - Section 18.4 -

*If the transport user asks for a message to be sent over an
  unreliable transport, and the result is an ICMP error, the behavior
  depends on the type of ICMP error. Host, network, port or protocol
  unreachable errors, or parameter problem errors SHOULD cause the
  transport layer to inform the transport user of a failure in sending.*

For IPv4 - Protocol Unreachable can be simulated by sending a SIP message over SCTP to a node which does not support SCTP.

I am confused for IPv6. There is no "Protocol Unreachable" error in ICMPv6. I do not have IPv6 set up to test. I have below questions -

1. Does IPv6/ICMPv6 not supports "Protocol Unreachable"?
2. RFC 4443 about type = 1, code = 3

   *If the reason for the failure to deliver cannot be mapped to any of
   other codes, the Code field is set to 3.  Example of such cases are
   an inability to resolve the IPv6 destination address into a
   corresponding link address, or a link-specific problem of some sort.*

Does it mean type = 1, code = 3 maps to "Protocol Unreachable"? The intent behind asking the question here is to get maximum information about this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at this through IPv4 glasses. The IPv4 packet header has a Protocol field, but the IPv6 packet header does not, so the Protocol Unreachable message does not apply to IPv6. The IPv6 packet header uses the Next Header field instead.

ICMPv6 does have the Parameter Problem Message, which includes a code for: *Unrecognized Next Header type encountered*.

Comment: Hi Ron, 
The question holds good for IPv6 next header also. What if "Next Header"  contains value (132) indicating SCTP transport as payload but destination does not support SCTP. Which ICMP error I am supposed to receive? 
The argument is valid for TCP, UDP also. Eventhough these two protocols are supported by every stack, still the question is theoretically valid.
Please correct, if any mistake.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, if a host receives an IPv6 packet destined for a protocol that the host does not support (SCTP, as your example), then the IPv6 in the network stack should generate an ICMPv6 Type 4 (_Parameter Problem_) message, with a Code 1 (_Unrecognized Next Header type encountered_), and usually a pointer of 40 (_Next Header_). This is all clearly documented in _[RFC 4443, Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMPv6) for the Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6) Specification, Section 3.4, Parameter Problem Message](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4443#section-3.4)_.